# prove AM-GM inequality for $n=k-1$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The question is assume the AM-GM inequality holds for $n$, prove for $n=k-1$.
After a bit of moving, I'm stuck at the following.

$\frac{x_1+...+x_{k-1}}{k-1}\geq \frac{k}{k-1}x_k^{1/k} ((x_1...x_{k-1})^{1/k}-x_k^\frac{k-1}{k})$

What do I do next? Also please elaborate if you are giving hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let
\begin{eqnarray*}
X=x_k= \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_{k-1}}{k-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_{k}}{k}= \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_{k-1}+ \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_{k-1}}{k-1}}{k} =\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_{k-1}}{k-1} =X.
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
X \geq \sqrt[k] {x_1 \cdots x_{k-1} X}
\end{eqnarray*}
raise this to the power of $k$, divivde through by $X$ & then take the $(k-1)^{th}$ root.

Comment: This is placing an assumption. Doesnt that limit the scope of solution?

Comment: Why can't we solve for arbitrary $x_k$?

Comment: From the question we assume that inequality holds for $\frac{x_1+...+x_k}{k}\geq(x_1...x_k)^\frac{1}{k}$, by placing such assumption, aren't we saying it is only true for $x_{k-1}$ if $x_k$ is a specific value?

Comment: We have $\frac{x_1+...+x_k}{k} \geq (x_1...x_k)^\frac{1}{k}$ is true. We choose a value for $x_k$ and then we show that $\frac{x_1+...+x_{k-1}}{k-1}\geq (x_1...x_{k-1})^\frac{1}{k-1}$.